# Editing Data Set Using Custom Function

Tags: r

I am having some trouble making changes to my data set using a function. I'd like to use a function because I will have to create multiple new columns using the same criteria.

First, I would like to make some changes in my Num column based on criteria in my Activity column. Then I would like to create a new column called Freq that assigns values based on criteria in my Num column.

My current code doesn't seem to be making the desired changes in my Num column but does apply the change to my new Freq column. For example, my function specifies to apply 0 if Activity == "No". While this change isn't made when I run the code, my Freq column seems to recognize the change being made and applies the correct value. Additionally, "Frequently" is showing up in my Freq column where Num is NA.

I'm sure something is wrong with my function. Any help would be great!

```
library(tidyverse)

Activity <- c(rep("NA", 5), rep("No Answer", 5), rep("No", 5), rep("Don't Know", 5), rep("Yes",5))
Num <- c(rep("NA", 5), rep("0", 5), rep("NA", 5), rep("0", 5), 1,2,3,4,5)
data <- data.frame(Activity, Num)


freq_func <- function(Activity, Num) {
  Num <- as.numeric(Num)
  Num <- ifelse(Activity == "No Answer", NA, 
           ifelse(Activity == "No", 0, 
           ifelse(Activity == "Don't Know", NA, Num)))
  ifelse(Num == 0, "None",
         ifelse(Num > 0 & Num < 5, "Rarely", 
         ifelse(Num > 4 & Num <60, "Frequently", 
         ifelse(Num > 60, "Almost Always", NA))))
}

test <- data %>% 
  mutate(Freq = freq_func(Activity, Num))
```

Comment: Because it is only updating within the function env and the return value is only for the 'Freq'.  Also, your columns are `factor` so you instead of `as.numeric` it would be `as.numeric(as.character(Num))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I'm posting the solution below.

Comment: Glad to know that you were able to fix it

Answer (score 1):

This worked taking into account @akrun's comment

```
library(tidyverse)

Activity <- c(rep("NA", 5), rep("No Answer", 5), rep("No", 5), rep("Don't Know", 5), rep("Yes",5))
Num <- c(rep("NA", 5), rep("0", 5), rep("NA", 5), rep("0", 5), 1,2,3,4,5)
data <- data.frame(Activity, Num)


col_edit <- function(Activity, Num) {
  Num <- as.numeric(as.character(Num))
  ifelse(Activity == "No Answer", NA,
  ifelse(Activity == "No", 0,
  ifelse(Activity == "Don't Know", NA, Activity)))
}


freq_func <- function(Num) {
  ifelse(Num == 0, "None",
         ifelse(Num > 0 & Num < 5, "Rarely", 
         ifelse(Num > 4 & Num <60, "Frequently", 
         ifelse(Num > 60, "Almost Always", NA))))
}

test <- data %>% 
  mutate(Num = col_edit(Activity, Num)) %>% 
  mutate(Freq = freq_func(Num))
```